# Unity Facebook login fails when denying permissions, but succeeds when granting. Returns error Unexpected call to LoginManager.onActivityResult

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine

I am getting completely stuck on a Facebook login problem in my Unity Android app. I am testing permission flow. When I let the app log in and grant the requested permission, Facebook happily logs me in, but if I deny a permission then it just flat out refuses the login.

This worked two days prior, so that I could log my user in, then check for the denied permissions and re-prompt or tell my app not to ask again.

Now I get the following output when I l try to log in and deny a permission

> 2021/06/09 12:16:42.012 27863 28095 Info Unity  Facebook not logged in {"callback_id":"4","key_hash":"Dd-----------arWY=\n","error":"Unexpected call to LoginManager.onActivityResult"} Accesstoken null

from my debug.log line

```
Debug.Log(" Facebook not logged in " + result.RawResult + " Accesstoken " + result.AuthenticationToken.ToStringNullOk());
```

Here is the code involved in the login process. I am a little new to integrating Facebook so it may be that I just missed something obvious, but so far no amount of research has helped me solve this.

```
public void Login(){
     perms = FilterFBPermissions(masterPermissions); //new List<string>(){"public_profile", "email", "user_friends"};

    Debug.Log(fbDebugString + " login perms " + perms.Count);
    
    FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(perms, AuthCallback);
    
}

public void FBLogout() {
    FB.LogOut ();
} 

/// <summary>
/// After Login.
/// </summary>
private void AuthCallback (ILoginResult result) {

    if (FB.IsLoggedIn) {
        
                              //            Debug.Log (result.RawResult);
        FB.API ("me?fields=name,picture.width(400).height(400)", HttpMethod.GET, ProfileDetailsCallback); // Get Facebook Profile Data After Login.
        CheckFBPermissions(); //Manie Check the permissions granted by the user via facebook login
    } else {
        
        Debug.Log(" Facebook not logged in " + result.RawResult + " Accesstoken " + result.AuthenticationToken.ToStringNullOk());
        setCallbackData (null);
        Debug.Log("User cancelled login");
    }
}
```

### Update

I was on 9.0 Unity sdk. Tried moving to v11 to resolve. No change. Ran code from another project that was working a few days ago, same issue.  Starting to think this is a Facebook issue.

Is there a way to get a list of denied permissions without the access token?

### Update

I have decided to file a bug report with Facebook since it seems to me to be coming from their side. You can find it at https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/4588988171131169/

Answer (score 0):

This issue has resolved itself without me touching my code! Today the login on my app works again but with a different permission window.

May have been fixed by FB dev team suspect this was a temporary issue, just updating for anyone who comes across this thread in future,

Any one else who knows more or could explain better, feel free to jump in.

We all learn together.